# how to convert two-columned cell array into matrix with points (each pair of elements from each row of cell array) MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have an cell Array (input) like this:

```
A(1,1) = {[1 2]};   A(1,2) = {[4 5 6]};
```

now for each row of A (in this case only 1) I would like to obtian the vector of points like this:

```
A_row1 =[ 1 4; 1 5; 1 6; 2 4; 2 5; 2 6]
```

I wonder if there is any method to cope with this without a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
[x, y] = ndgrid(A{1}, A{2})
B = [x(:) y(:)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```
B = sortrows([repmat(A{1}',size(A{2},2),1) repmat(A{2}',size(A{1},2),1)])

B =

 1     4
 1     5
 1     6
 2     4
 2     5
 2     6
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! But I noticed that sometimes it doesn't want to work as it should. There were results where I obtain repetitions of this same points. Finally I used the answer posted below.

Comment: @Karolina, I don't see where you would get repetitions, but you're probably right. Just use the answer that is best for you =)